# Laravel Queue - Waiting on jobs to finish before dispatching next batch

Tags: php, laravel, queue, beanstalkd

I have a synchronous process that takes about 7 hours to finish and I'm trying to convert it into jobs to speed it up. The problem is I need to make sure all jobs in step1 are finished before I dispatch step2 jobs.

I'm using **[Beanstalkd](https://github.com/beanstalkd/beanstalkd)** as my queue driver in Laravel. One possible solution that comes to my mind is running a while loop constantly checking if the queue is empty but that doesn't guarantee the last few jobs being done.

Here is what I'm trying to do in a nutshell:

```
//Step 1
ModelA::chunk(1000,function($rows){
  foreach($rows as $row){
      Dispatch(new JobA($row);
  }
}

//I Need To Make Sure STEP1 is Done Before I Proceed

//Step 2
ModelB::chunk(1000,function($rows){
  foreach($rows as $row){
      Dispatch(new JobB($row);
  }
}
```

I'm also open to a different way of doing this.

Comment: Maybe Laravel's [Job chaining](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#job-chaining) useful is useful in this case ?

Comment: @RamyHerrira I'm not sure how I can chain this. Notice that I want the elements of for loop to run as a job

Answer (score 1):

Probably Laravel 8 Queue Batch may work.
If not, try this package https://github.com/spatie/async